# Level Of Detail Surfaces from Multilevel B Splines

Tags: opengl, graphics, geometry

I recently read the paper [Scattered Data Interpolation
with Multilevel B-Splines](http://www.postech.ac.kr/~leesy/ftp/tvcg97.pdf).

Consider a surface z(x,y), xmin<=x<=xmax, ymin<=y<=ymax.  Next consider a 4x4 grid of "control" points (black): P0 so that the surface covers the central cell:

[image]

The z value of any point (red) on the surface (yellow) may be approximated as a weighted sum of the values in control points. The weights are the distances to the control points.

Next divide the center cell into 2x2 cells and add a 1 cell border around the surface. The result is the control grid P1 (blue). A more accurate approximation of the z value in the red point may be found by adding a distance weighted sum of the 4x4 closest control points in P1 to the initial approximation above.

Likewise we can repeatedly half the size of the cells and create new control grids: P2, P3, ...Pn. Each grid is a new "level".

Each new grid add more detail to the surface. The control grids become increasingly sparse;
 the values only differ from 0 where the surface changes abruptly relative to its sourrounding points.

The result is possible storage scheme that should be able to store a surface with a great amount of detail with relatively little memory.

**How can this be used in Level Of Detail algorithm?**

For each LOD tile of the surface I would like to triangulate using the control points up to certain level on the GPU (preferably using OpenGL), the level being determined by how far away from the camera the tile is.

That way hopefully; an incredibly detailed surface could be stored using minimal of memory and viewed from different angles and zoomed in/out on quickly.

**Any ideas or pointers on how to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a view dependent LOD selection factor and David Luebke's [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123991811) on LOD describes several techniques.

The algorithm you use is progressive and any LOD that applies to a classic technique like 
[Progressive meshes](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/hoppe/proj/pm/) applies to yours.

Note that if you use this progressive reconstruction algorithm for texture mapping rather than a mesh, you will have the exact same filtering situation as Perlin [noise](http://graphics.cs.kuleuven.be/publications/LLCDDELPZ10STARPNF/).

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL 4.0 and onward, support [Geometry Shaders](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader). They can be used to generate tessellate primitives on the fly. So you will pass the tile and control point information information to the shader, where you'll tessellate your primitive further.